# Why does it say 'Could not connect to server.' when I try to login to my Mojang account and how do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open my launcher and type in my correct e-mail and my correct password, I press login and it says: 'Could not connect to server'. Does anyone know how to fix this or is Minecraft down?

Comment: Minecraft servers are not currently down.  You can check the status of their servers at [https://help.mojang.com/](https://help.mojang.com/).  My first recommendation is checking your firewall settings.  An easy way to rule this out is to temporarily disable your firewall.  If it connects properly with the firewall disabled, you have to configure your firewall.

Comment: I have checked my firewall settings but it still says: 'Could not connect to server.' when I try to login and it won't even let me play.

Comment: @IronAnvil And yes, I have checked their status and turned firewall off. It still says 'Could not connect to server.' and I don't know what else to do. I've deleted Minecraft and downloaded it again and even bought it again but it doesn't do anything. Have you got any more reccomendations?

Comment: Ok.  A handful of things to try.  If you have Windows, run launcher as administrator.  Restart router, modem, and computer.  Run internet speed test from computer.  Temporarily disable virus software if you have it.  Uninstall and reinstall java and make sure you install the proper version (32 or 64 bit depending on your system).  If none of this works backup saves, resource packs, and servers.dat file and then delete the .minecraft folder.

Comment: @IronAnvil Yes, I have tried everything and it still says on launcher that it could not connect to server and on the Minecraft website that they had a problem logging me in. I don't know what has happened and it started when I opened up my computer and opened the launcher. I then put in my details and it just says it couldn't.

Comment: I am out of ideas.  At this point I recommend you head over to the [Mojang Portal](https://help.mojang.com/).  See what they have to say.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just today and I fixed it by deleting McAfee Safe Connect! It is very annoying cause it basically automatically installs itself. So check if you have that installed on your PC. 
P.S. They have a tutorial on how to uninstall it on the McAfee website.